# Changing UI language on-the-fly

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, localization, internationalization

I need to support UI language change through the application menu. Localized strings store in resource files. I use [this](http://jachman.wordpress.com/2009/06/10/how-to-localize-silverlight-applications-the-smart-way/) approach. It works fine, but I one problem.
How I can change UI language on-the-fly, without reloading application?

I try to google this problem - many advises to implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface. 
But, I still can't figure out how it works.

Do you know  any on-fly-changing-SL-application? Please show me how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using the Reactive Framework?

I have an application where the user can choose the display language/culture at runtime. I use the Reactive Framework to provide an IObservable to push out the language change event.

UI controls that need to change in response to the language change event have a attached behavior that registers their interest.